# Variables defined on page for use in link paths

Tags: html, variables

I have a web site with three "courses", where the difference between each is pretty small. 95% of a page might be identical for all three versions, with just a few links needing differentiation, like this.

```
<a href="http://Location.com/A/Download.xml" target="_blank">LINK NAME</a>
<a href="http://Location.com/B/Download.xml" target="_blank">LINK NAME</a>
<a href="http://Location.com/C/Download.xml" target="_blank">LINK NAME</a>
```

Currently I am managing this manually, but I wonder if it's possible to define a variable and use it in the path, so the only change needed is the one defining the variable and all links are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML provides no such feature.

You can generate your HTML using a template with whatever combination of programming language and template language suits your taste. These will make that possible.

You can do this either as a build step before publishing the site or on demand with server side code that runs each time the page is requested.

---

A simple example using Template-Toolkit:

```
[% SET link_paths = [ "A", "B", "C" ]; %]

[% FOR link_path IN link_paths %]
<a href="http://Location.com/[% link_path | html %]/Download.xml" target="_blank">LINK NAME</a>
[% END %]
```

Comment: The thing is that the pages are constantly updated, and it's a WordPress site with a very specific theme, so messing with Templates may be beyond me. I suspect the answer is to edit one page, then copy past that HTML out of the WordPress editor, into TextWrangler and do a find/replace, then copy past into the next page. Not ideal, but better than eyeballing. Thanks for verifying there is no native HTML approach.